# Python: need the name of index

Tags: python, pandas

I am still very new to Python so forgive me if I do not make full sense. I have a long DataFrame and it has two columns: one with the name of tennis players and the other one with the number of titles won. I am trying to retrieve the player with the most titles won but by only showing the name of the player and not the number of titles. I tried using **`max()`** to find out the player with most titles won but I cannot figure out how to retrieve the name of the player. The **"players"** column is the index.

As I said, I tried using **`max()`** but it throws an error **`"TypeError: 'Index' object is not callable"`**

```
 max(df['Titles'], key=df.index)
```

Many thanks

Comment: `df.set_index('name')['num_titles'].idxmax()`

Comment: if that doesn't work send us part of your dataframe/csv data, easier.

Comment: Worked like a champ. Thanks so much!

Comment: please read this[mre]

Answer (score 0):

You can use a lambda expression , it's like a function that simplify lot of things , like your case " selecting the max of elements refering to the number of wins " , you can do it like this :

```
c = max(list, key= lambda x : x[1] )
print( c[0] ) # prinx the name
```